# pass more than one variable to php script using $.ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this script:

```
             var wall_user_id =  "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>";

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "user_id=" + wall_user_id,
            success: function () {
                $('ul#posts').prepend(wall_post);

            }
        });//end success function
```

that send wall_user_id to the php script:

```
      <?php
      require 'core/functions/init.php';

      $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO wall (user_id) VALUES('.$user_id.')';
      mysql_query($sql);
      ?>
```

this works fine but it doesn't if I try to add more values like this:

```
         var wall_user_id =  "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>";
             var wall_userimage = "<?php echo $user_data['imagename']; ?>";

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "user_id=" + wall_user_id +"userimage="+ wall_userimage,
            success: function () {
                $('ul#posts').prepend(wall_post);

            }
        });//end success function
```

and insert.php:

```
 <?php
      require 'core/functions/init.php';

      $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
      $userimage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userimage']);

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO wall (user_id, image) VALUES('.$user_id.','.$userimage.')';
      mysql_query($sql);
      ?>
```

it doesn't inserts any values into the database.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think people should state why they downvote so we can learn from our mistakes. Probably you guys knew everything about programming before you were born. I just started (few months ago) and i'm really keen to learn if you tell what was wrong if my question. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass as many values as you want in the `data`:

```
data: { user_id: wall_user_id, userimage: wall_userimage }
```

and in your example use `&` to separate parameters:

```
data: "user_id=" + wall_user_id + "&userimage=" + wall_userimage
```

But the first method is the recommended way because jQuery takes care of properly url encoding the values. With your example if you wanted to do it properly you should have written:

```
data: "user_id=" + encodeURIComponent(wall_user_id) + "&userimage=" + encodeURIComponent(wall_userimage)
```

which obviously is way too much code for this. So use the first approach.

Comment: thanks.... I have to wait to more minutes to accept your question... you have been too fast ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Data query string is wrong. You forgot the `&`

`data : "user_id=" + wall_user_id +"&userimage="+ wall_userimage`

Or you can use object

```
data : { 'user_id': wall_user_id, 'userimage': wall_userimage }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple variable cannot be sent like that . You are posting the values as below
 data: "user_id=" + wall_user_id +"userimage="+ wall_userimage

This wont work for multiple variables. You can do something like below

$.post("  address to which you need to post ",{ "user_id": wall_user_id , "userimage" : wall_userimage}, function(response)
    {
        ...........
    });

or

data:{ "user_id" : wall_user_id , "userimage" : wall_userimage }

The data should be passed as an array